# .htaccess rewrite not routing

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite `example.ee/api/game/2` to `example.ee/vivule/api/game/2`

In the htaccess file I use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ /vivule/api/$1 [NC]
```

But when I go to `example.ee/api/game/2`, incorrect content is displayed (as if no rewrite happened at all).

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any other directives in your .htaccess file? Presumably this .htaccess file is in the document root? mod_rewrite enabled etc? (If you add rubbish in the first line do you get an error?)

Comment: What do you mean by `incorrect content`? Are your css/js not rendering?

Comment: @w3dk If I write rubbish, I get the 500 error. I do have mod_rewrite enabled.

Comment: @anubhava emm, it doesn't work, I don't get the content I want.

Comment: @anubhava well I'm getting 404, but since I'm using php slim, it gives a different 404 error than the regualr: Here check yourself: http://vivule.ee/api/game/2

Comment: @anubhava tested, it is enabled. Just for extra info - the htaccess file is in a subdirectory (first child from root).

Comment: @anubhava Even if I put it into root there is no change (also note I'm using this in root .htaccess) (since I'm running multiple domains from one server)

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?vivule\.ee$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^vivule/ /vivule%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]

Comment: With that rule in in place you don't need `RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ /vivule/api/$1 [NC]` rule.

Comment: @anubhava I thought the same, but if you check here:
http://vivule.ee/vivule/api/game/2 , it gets the data
but if you go here, it does not: http://vivule.ee/api/game/2

Comment: The fact that slim generate 404 error is coming means root .htaccess rule is working fine. You can comment out that rule from site root and you will see Apache default 404 error